# entry above engulfing candle in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I am new to pine script. I have coded a pine script which detect the bullish engulfing candle and enters long **on open** of the next bullish engulfing candle. I am looking for the entry when price **crosses above the high of the engulfing candle** on the very next candle only by 0.1% if price doesn't cross then do nothing. Same **for the SL** when the **price crosses 0.1 %  below** the engulfing candle. For **take profit lets consider 1:2** at this point and **trail SL with close below 10 ema**.

Here is my code so far:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHvry.png)

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Cheers,
Kelly

Comment: The error message tells you what is wrong. You cannot call crossover with bool parameters. Your `bull` variable is of type bool.

Comment: True, recognize it. Any ways around it ? How can I work it out ?  Thank for your feed back.

Comment: You need to change your logic. Why do you want to use the `crossover` function? What do you want to calculate with your `bull` variable?

Comment: I wish I knew how to change the logic. Bull variable is to define bullish engulfing candle. The goal is to enter long when the price crosses few points above bullish engulfing.   Thanks for answering.